# Angular2 router - Auxiliary route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I do have a lazy loaded module which loads by default `LazyLoadedComponent` when I go to `/lazy`. So far, it's OK.

This component contains 2 router-outlet :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="aux"></router-outlet>
```

And the module has the following routes :

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LazyLoadedComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: NonAuxComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: AuxComponent,
        outlet: 'aux'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

When I go to `/lazy` I do have the 3 components loaded as expected.
But, if I want to change the path to display the `AuxComponent` like that :

```
{
   path: 'auxpath',
   component: AuxComponent,
   outlet: 'aux'
}
```

And I try to go to `/lazy(aux:auxpath)` it's not working.

I also tried to hit that url using the `routerLink` like that :

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { aux: 'auxpath' } }]">Load an auxiliary route</a>
```

But it's not working either.

[image]

Is this a bug with the router ? Is it just me missing out something here?

You can check out the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TiwzIoR8t57yRrx8zpaQ?p=preview) to make your own tests.

Comment: Hi Maxime. I was playing with outlets recently and it seems to be working. Do you know if your issue has been solved?

Comment: @AngularFrance so for it doesn't seem to be solved. I'll give another try later this week or next one if I can find some time :)
Thanks for getting in touch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying a lot of things, I ended up with the conclusion that it was probably a bug in `@angular/router`.

I created a [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13807), and it turns out that [one was already existing](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981) since august.