# Rendering child component content inside of parents router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, router-outlet

I have a problem with rendering child component content inside of 'parents' router-outlet.

Here is my main route:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'notary', loadChildren: 'app/notary/notary.module#NotaryModule' }
]
```

Where 'Login module' is eagerly loaded, and my 'Notary module' is lazy loaded.

My 'Notary module' has its own route which is:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {
    //<router-outlet> </router-outlet> i will call this one Wrapper router-oulet
    path: 'contracts', component: ContractWrapperComponent, children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'search', pathMatch:'full' },
        { path: 'search', component: ContractListComponent },
        //<router-outlet> </router-outlet> i will call this one contract children router-outlet
        { path: ':id', component: ContractInsertUpdateComponent, children: [               
           { path: 'persons', component: PersonListComponent },
           { path: 'person', component: PersonInsertEditComponent },
           { path: 'person/:id', component: PersonInsertEditComponent }]
        }]
}];
```

I would like (if possible) to load PersonInsertEditComponent (which is currently rendered inside of router-outlet i called contract children router-outlet) inside of first router-outlet (i called it Wrapper Router Outlet in code). 
However i have no idea how to do this. I've tried using outlet property, but it seems there is problem with outlet and lazy loading routes by this post - [Angular2 router - Auxiliary route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495093/angular2-router-auxiliary-route) and im getting same error as described in that question...

Thanks for help in advanced!

**UPDATE**

What i noticed is that it can be done by manipulating route a little bit to look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
       {
        //<router-outlet> </router-outlet> i will call this one Wrapper router-oulet
        path: 'contracts', component: ContractWrapperComponent, children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'search', pathMatch:'full' },
            { path: 'search', component: ContractListComponent },
            { path: ':id/person', component: PersonInsertEditComponent },
            { path: ':id/person/:id', component: PersonInsertEditComponent }
            //<router-outlet> </router-outlet> i will call this one contract children router-outlet
            { path: ':id', component: ContractInsertUpdateComponent, children: [               
               { path: 'persons', component: PersonListComponent }
               ]
            }]
    }];
```

So, by moving those 2 routes ( 'person','person/:id')  up one level, they get rendered inside of 'Wrapper router-outlet' which is just where i want em to be rendered, but this just doesn't seem right way to do it...Those routes should've been child routes, doing it this way makes them siblings with their parent...If anyone could point me in the right direction, i would really appreciate it.